# Better way to change parent div class name when click

Tags: jquery

How to change the UL class name(menu1) when click each LIs ?

For example,

when click "tab1", change UL's class name to "menu1".

when click "tab2", change UL's class name to "menu2".

when click "tab3", change UL's class name to "menu3".

This code is I tried.

```
<ul class="tab menu1">
   <li class="tab1">t1</li>
   <li class="tab2">t1</li>
   <li class="tab3">t1</li>
</ul>

<script>
$('.tab1').click(function(){
   $('.tab').addClass('menu1');
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu2');
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu3');
});

$('.tab2').click(function(){
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu1');
   $('.tab').addClass('menu2');
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu3');
});

$('.tab3').click(function(){
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu1');
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu2');
   $('.tab').addClass('menu3');
});
</script>
```

Any better way to make my code simpler ?

Comment: your code seems fine. What is the problem?

Comment: @AmmarCSE  yeah it works fine but my code looks stupid :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add `data-*` attributes to your `HTML`

```
<ul class="tab menu1">
   <li class="tab1" data-trigger-class="menu1">t1</li>
   <li class="tab2" data-trigger-class="menu2">t1</li>
   <li class="tab3" data-trigger-class="menu3">t1</li>
</ul>
```

Then, have your click handler(you only need one) use them

```
$('.tab li').click(function(){
   $('.tab').removeClass('menu1 menu2 menu3');
   $('.tab').addClass($(this).attr('data-trigger-class'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One efficient way is to use your li element's index to assign menu class.

HTML:

```
<ul class="tab">
   <li class="tabListItem">t1</li>
   <li class="tabListItem">t1</li>
   <li class="tabListItem">t1</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.tabListItem').click(function(){
    $('.tab').removeClass().addClass('tab').addClass('menu'+($(this).index()+1));
});
```